# Creating buffers on selected point layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, buffer, select

I try to create buffers of 5m on the selected points only (in ArcGIS 10.3):

[image]

The problem is that the buffer tool create buffers for all the features,  why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is important to keep in mind the difference between **data sources** and **layers**.  Layers are constructed upon data sources, but they have a *Query Definition* property which defines the maximum rows available, and a *Selection Set* which defines which features are highlighted.

When you start the Buffer dialog, there are TWO pickers available: 
[image: Buffer dialog]

The left picklist chooses among *layers*:
[image: layer picklist]

While the folder button chooses among *data sources*:
[image: data explorer]

(You can also "Drag-n-drop" data sources from the Catalog window.)

The difference in behavior you are seeing is based on whether you have a layer or a data source in the *Input Features* picker:

- If the input is a layer, then it uses the current selection environment within the query definition, and bufferes the resulting rows.
- If the input is a data source, it uses **all** the features (as if no query definition were defined, and no selection made)

For example, if I open the attribute table of the "cities" layer and query all cities with "Lake" in their name:

[image: Select by Attributes]

And buffer based on the "cities" layer:
[image: Layer buffer]

Then the resulting buffer only contains buffers around the selected features:
[image: buffered layer]

However, if I buffer the data source:
[image: Source buffer]

Then I get what I asked for (though maybe not what was intended):
[image: buffered source]

There are times when it becomes necessary to create a temporary feature class by exporting the selected set to a new feature class, but for the most part, layers have rendered that requirement obsolete (you just need to choose the right Input Features).

Answer (score 0):

ArcMap usually works correctly but sometimes not. Try restarting software and/or computer.

- If those won't help try selecting desired features again.
- Go to Table    of Contents.
- Right mouse click on desired point layer. Selection ->    Create
  Layer From Selected Features.
- A new layer is created and    appearing in Table of Contents.
- Try buffering with new temporary    selection layer.

Comment: Restarting the software and/or computer should ***not*** be the first step in diagnosing a problem in ArcMap.